# D3.js SVG path corruption on brush and zoom (stacked areas chart)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming, nan

I am struggling with the brushed() / zoomed() functions on a stacked areas chart.

Whereas the first generation of the chart is perfectly drawn, the SVG path appear corrupted / collects some NaNs as soon as brushed() or zoomed() are called, hence causing some areas to disappear.

The problem is within a for loop in the brushed() or zoomed() functions, where I call this kind of line :

```
focus.select(".area."+customString[i]).attr("d", window['d3_AreaVariable_'+i]]);
```

The chart is well drawn before, but as soon as I do those selects in the brushed() function, attr("d") returns some NaNs in the SVG path (on console, attr("d") before brushed()'s select returns correct values without NaNs).

Interestingly, some areas (first and last one) does not get corrupted and stay zoomable and brushable (so it should work for all !?) but many others disappear because of the corruption.

Maybe storing those d3.area() variables in the window object is not a good practice ?

Not sure what I am missing but any clue(s) / hint about what could cause that ?

Here is my brushed() function.
Thanks.

```
function brushed() {

  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return;
  s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));

  for(var i = 0; i < someArrayOfStrings.length; i++)
  { // problem here
    focus.select(".area."+someArrayOfStrings[i]).attr("d", window[someArrayOfStrings[i]]); 
  }

  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  focus.select(".axis--xY").call(xAxisYear);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with v5. Please try it with v4... if the problem persists, edit your title removing the *v5*.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I just checked and the problem is still there with V4 so edited the title accordingly.